# How can I find the substrings from the NSTextCheckingResult objects in swift?

Tags: swift2

I wonder how it is possible to find substrings from a NSTextCheckingResult object. I have tried this so far:

```
import Foundation {
    let input = "My name Swift is Taylor Swift "
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "Swift|Taylor", options:NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive) 
    let matches = regex.matchesInString(input, options: [], range:   NSMakeRange(0, input.characters.count))
    for match in matches {
    // what will be the code here?
}
```

Comment: Please explain more about your Question

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
import Foundation

let input = "My name Swift is Taylor Swift "// the input string where we will find for the pattern
let nsString = input as NSString

let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "Swift|Taylor", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)
//matches will store the all range objects in form of NSTextCheckingResult 
let matches = regex.matchesInString(input, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, input.characters.count)) as Array<NSTextCheckingResult>

for match in matches {
    // what will be the code
    let range = match.range
    let matchString = nsString.substringWithRange(match.range) as String
    print("match is \(range) \(matchString)")
}
```

Comment: it is giving error: cannot convert value of type 'String' to type 'NSString' in coercion
let nsString = input as NSString

Comment: I was using this [link](https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/?cm_mmc=developerWorks-_-dWdevcenter-_-swift-_-lp&cm_mc_uid=87371904663714544642935&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1456370325#/repl) to run the swift codes. is it a problem ??

Answer (score 5):

Here is code that works for Swift 3. It returns array of String

```
    results.map {
        String(text[Range($0.range, in: text)!])
    }
```

So overall example could be like this:

```
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
    let results = regex.matches(in: text,
                                range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
    return results.map {
        String(text[Range($0.range, in: text)!])
    }
```

Comment: This seemed to be the cleanest and 'swiftiest' solution, sadly it crashed on the second try when force-unwrapping the range while testing with emojies.

Comment: @JanSchlorf by doing something like the following you can get rid of the force-unwrap:

```swift
results
    .compactMap { match in
        Range(match.range, in: value)
            .flatMap { String(value[$0]) }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put this code inside the for loop. The `str` will contain the string that matches.

`let range = match.range
let str = (input as NSString).substringWithRange(range)`